# Parsing different Formats of JSON to a Single Object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a Java Spring web application. In that, I have to call a webservice URL and it returns a JSON, which I am parsing to one object.

Suppose the Result JSON String is

```
{ "name" : "myname", "type" : "type1", "createdDate" : "02-1-2014", "submittedDate" : "02-19-2014"  }
```

My Java class is **ParseJson.java**

```
public class JsonParse implements Serializable {
 private String name;
 private String type;
 private Date createdDate
 privatr Date submittedDate

 //getters and setters...

}
```

I am converting the JSON String to Object using org-codehaus-Jackson.

```
String strResponse= /*web service URL and returning the above JSON String */
JsonParse jsonParse=new JsonParse();
jsonParse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(strResponse,
                    JsonParse.class);
```

Suppose I am getting different the With additional values or some changed.

```
{ "name" : "myname", "type" : "type1", "openDate" : "02-1-2014", "closedDate" : "02-19-2014"  }
```

Here is the problem occurs while parsing to **JsonParse** Object. To parse that I need one more object that has updated fields and values.

So I'll have to create different objects for different versions or modifications. 
That's difficult. So is there any better way of parsing any JSON string to a common Java object in a generic way So any JSON format can be parsed?

Comment: How many such variations can you think of? If it is something as simple as a field or two that may change, you can probably alias them. In more serious cases such as changing the structure of JSON, you'll have to think of a better way to model your data, such as using maps.

Comment: That I cannot be sure. It may be many variations as I think of. How to alias?